# Passing span ID to jQuery variable : not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
jQuery(".tags").on('click',function(){ //to show a tagged pose
    var ids = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(ids);

    var x_cord = $(this).attr('data-x');
    var y_cord = $(this).attr('data-y');

    alert($('#'+ids).length);
    $($(ids)).css({color:'gray'});

    $("#overshow").css({
        top: y_cord,
        left: x_cord,
        width:'100px',
        height:'100px',
        position:'absolute',
        border:'3px solid red'
    });

    $('#overshow').show('fast'); //.delay(1000).hide('slow');
});
```

This is my piece of code. I am getting alert as '1' but css property is not applied.

Comment: Are you sure `ids = $(this).attr('id');` will give you `id` as it will search only on the given selector. If you can share your HTML that will be good.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the id selector in the `.css` call:

```
$("#" + ids).css({color:'gray'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `ids` is the id of the current element(referred by `this`), you can use the dom element reference `this` to access the element, there is no need to use a id selector

```
$(this).css({color:'gray'});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this key for get the current element

```
$("#" + ids).css({'color':'gray'});
```

or

```
 $(this).css({'color':'gray'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$($(ids)).css({color:'gray'})
```

should be

```
$("#"+ids).css({'color':'gray'})
```

Comment: @DineshPatil As @sudhar have mentioned you have also missed `'` around `color` attribute

Comment: I have chaged that one also, but still I am getting problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Without html code, it is hard to help you. Please share your HTML code.

1. The following line is strange:
   `ids = $(this).attr('id');` you did not prefix it by `var`
2. If the clicked item is which one you want to set to gray, you can use `$(this)` directly.
3. You can replace `.attr("data-x")` by `.data("x")`
4. You can chain functions in jquery.

*Check the following snippet:*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tags").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
     color:'gray'
    });
    $("#overshow").css({
      top: $(this).data('y'),
      left: $(this).data('x'),
      width:'100px',
      height:'100px',
      position:'absolute',
      border:'3px solid red'
    }).show('fast');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="tags" data-x="2" data-y="2">tag 1, x2, y2</button>
<button class="tags" data-x="4" data-y="4">tag 2, x4, y4</button>
<button class="tags" data-x="6" data-y="6">tag 3, x6, y6</button>
<button class="tags" data-x="8" data-y="8">tag 4, x8, y8</button>
<div id="overshow-wrapper" style="position: relative">
  <div id="overshow">
    OVERSHOW
  </div>
</div>
```